# Quando usar PX ou % nos posicionamentos?

Tags: css, posicionamento

Em elementos internos do layout, para posicionar em margin ou coordenada, quando se deve usar PX e %?

Comment: Não sei se é só isto que você quer realmente saber, se não for, elabora mais a pergunta, mas a resposta seria só: use `px` para *layout* fixo e `%` para *layout* fluido, adaptável.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Depende da sua necessidade e o contexto do layout. Se for um layout responsivo use `%` para determinar o posicionamento. Se for um layout estático, use `PX`.

Lembrando que `%` é um unidade de medida dinâmica, ou seja, o elemento com posicionamento por porcentagem vai variar de acordo com seu elemento pai, por exemplo:

```
<div id="elemento_pai">
   <div id="elemento_filho"></div>
</div>

#elemento_pai {width:100%; height:100%}
#elemento_filho {width:50%; height:100%; margin-left:50%}
```

Esse exemplo vai fazer com que o elemento filho mude de tamanho e posicionamento de acordo com elemento pai, sempre mantendo a base esquerda do elemento filho alinhada ao centro do elemento pai.

E a unidade de medida em `PX`, é uma unidade de medida estática, ou seja, ela não altera de acordo com algum elemento pai, ela por si só já define o posicionamento e o tamanho do elemento sem depender de outro elemento, sendo assim, um posicionamento com `PX` ficará estático exatamente aonde ela for definida.

Comment: Mas se eu usar media queries para cada padrao de resolução em px. Funcionaria?

Comment: @ropbla9 Nesse caso você teria um tamanho fixo para cada resolução. Ele mudaria sim de tamanho ao passar de uma resolução para outra, mas dentro da resolução o tamanho ficaria inalterado. Já com `%` qualquer redimensionamento da janela do browser faria com que o elemento mudasse de tamanho, sem quebras.

Comment: É. Mas se a tela for muito pequena acaba que tudo vai ficar pequeno demais na estrutura original, correto?

Comment: Ficaria sim, tudo pequeno. Isso seria bem relativo ao tamanho proposto em cada media querie.

Comment: Mas pra fazer uma media querie pra cada resolução eu aconselharia você pensar em fazer seu layout com porcentagem, te evitaria muito código.